# Question from Flutter novice developer about 'await'

Tags: dart, flutter, async-await

I'm an iOS developer starting to look into Flutter. I'm following [this tutorial from Ray Wenderlich](https://www.raywenderlich.com/116-getting-started-with-flutter) and I'm facing a strange behaviour from this code.

```
_loadData() async {
   var dataURL = "https://api.github.com/orgs/raywenderlich/members";
   var response = await http.get(dataURL);
   setState(() {
      _members = json.decode(response.body);
   });
 }
```

Problem is that execution is stopped at `var response = await http.get(dataURL);`

I know is related to the `await` but I'm not sure why is happening. On the example code from the [http package](https://pub.dev/packages/http) is using a similar code.
Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So, the reason of the unresponsive await was due to the Android simulator. I don't know why but connection is not working on the simulator. I tested with the iOS simulator and worked.

Answer (score 0):

if it is stopped it might be because the url does not return anything, maybe because the url is wrong? also i think string should use single quotations ' instead of ". try replacing it with single quotations?

Comment: The URL is working. If you open in the browser you'll see a JSON response. I tested with single quotations but isn't working neither.